# Who are my three friends?

Tags: riddle

I'm just a regular guy, but I have three best friends.

When I meet the first, he usually sends me two letters.

When I meet the second, she tends to leave me just as I am, sometimes having passed me a letter.

When I meet the third, he presents me with his final testament.

**Who am I, and who are my friends?**

<sub>Inspired by [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/46481/5373), but the solution is (almost certainly) different.</sub>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe that [demonofthemist](/users/4956/demonofthemist) is very close. 
Building on and branching out from [his answer](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/46532/19765#46542), you are:

> A verb in English. 
> At the risk of getting too technical,
> you are the infinitive form of a regular verb in English.

Your three friends are:

> The three tenses of verbs (past, present, and future).

---

When I meet the first, he usually sends me two letters.

> **Past Tense**
>
> The past tense of a regular verb in English is formed by appending “ed”.
>
> For example: “ask” → “asked”,  “answer” → “answered”
>
>
> (Note that I mentioned “regular” verb. 
> There are “irregular” verbs that do not follow this rule. 
> For example,
> the two verbs in the above sentence from the OP are both irregular:
> “meet” → “met”,  “send” → “sent”)

When I meet the second,
she tends to leave me just as I am, sometimes having passed me a letter.

> **Present Tense**
>
> The present tense of a verb in English is usually the base/root/infinitive,
> but an “s” gets appended when it is used with third-person singular subject.
>
> For example: I type,  you type,  he type**s**
>
>
> A few irregular verbs don’t follow this pattern; for example,
> I am,  you are,  he is;    I have,  you have,  he has

When I meet the third, he presents me with his final testament.

> **Future Tense**
>
> The future tense of a verb in English is (almost?) always formed
> by adding the auxiliary word “will”.
>
> For example: I will type,  you will type,  he will type
>
> The legal document specifying how a person’s estate should be distributed
> after he dies is called a “last **will** and testament” (emphasis added).

---

Alternatively, it could be that you are

> Ebenezer Scrooge

and your “friends” are

> the ghosts of Christmas past, present, and future.       :-)

Comment: i'd go for scrooge :)

Comment: Bingo, you got it! And you don't have to worry about irregular verbs, since the question says "I'm a *regular* guy :-) There are also a couple of other funny bits of wordplay - see if you can spot them.

Comment: I feel my answer as foolish now :D +1

Comment: @randal'thor:  No, you're too clever / tricky / cryptic / arcane for me — I can't spot any other funny bits of wordplay.

Comment: @PeregrineRook You didn't spot the word "passed" and "presents" in there? I couldn't resist ... :-D

Comment: @randal'thor: Arrrgh. It struck me that "passed" was a slightly odd word to use in that context, but I didn't recognize either of them as clues.

Comment: @randal'thor: Well! It’s about time! (Thanks, and Happy New Year.)

Comment: P.S. Pun not planned, but deliberately left in when detected.    :-)   ⁠

Answer (score 13):

You are:

> A **Verb** in English

Your three friends are:

> Three forms of verb (*Simple, Past & Past participle*)

---

When I meet the first, he usually sends me two letters.

> **Past Form**
>
>
>  When a verb is in past form it is usually appended a *ED* 
>
>  *Example* : `Gift -> Gifted`, `Walk -> Walked`
>
>
>  But this is not mandatory 
>
>  *Example* : `Do -> Did`, `Go -> Went`

When I meet the second, she tends to leave me just as I am, sometimes having passed me a letter.

> **Simple Form**
>
>
>  When a verb is in simple or present form it is used as is, But get appended a *S* when used with third-person singular noun or pronoun. 
>
>
>  *Example* : When he *get**s*** angry, his face turns red
>
>
>  Note : I'll mention that sometime *ES* is used instead on *S*, e.g. `Do -> Does`

When I meet the third, he presents me with his final testament.

> **Past Participle Form**
>
>
>  The past Past participle form of a verb indicates past or completed action or time.
>
>
>  *Example* : `Do -> Done`, `Go -> Gone`, `Awake -> Awoken`

Comment: Not bad at all. Maybe you got it.

Comment: Good one.... +1

Comment: Go --> Gone, I think...

Comment: Very very close, but the third part isn't quite there (doesn't fit with "testament"). Definitely +1, though I'll probably have to accept Peregrine Rook's answer instead.

Comment: Thanks guys! @randal'thor Sure! I overlooked "testament" and interpreted it differantly :)

Answer (score 5):

You might be:

> Oxygen

And your 3 best friends are:

> Hydrogen, Carbon, and Nitrogen (?)

When I meet the first, he usually sends me two letters

> Hydrogen reacts with Oxygen to give H2O, so that's 2 Hs

When I meet the second, she tends to leave me just as I am, sometimes having passed me a letter

> Carbon and oxygen do not usually react at normal conditions, but they do you get CO2, so that's only 1 C

When I meet the third, he presents me with his final testament

> All I can think of is NOx, but that means "night" so I might be on the wrong track.

Answer (score 3):

And the simple guy is

> Octopus

When I meet the first, he usually sends me two letters.

> Meet O(which are you)  and it gives two letters CT

When I meet the second, she tends to leave me just as I am, sometimes having passed me a letter.

> Meet C it gives two letters T and O(again)

When I meet the third, he presents me with his final testament

> Meet T and it presents you with OPUS which is a synonym for testament or will.

And the tree friends are

> OCT(October) :)

Comment: Ironic it's December now, though, right?